# how to set id to an element inside tiny mce

Tags: tinymce

I want to add an Id to the element which is being edited using a tine mce instance ? Is there any way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You need to get the selections parent node and apply the attribute id there:

```
ed.onDesiredEvent.add(function(editor, event) {
    node = editor.selection.getNode();
    node.setAttribute('id','the_id_to_be_assigned');
}
```

Comment: what about your other tinymce questions? (are they still open to you?)

Comment: Thanks Thariama :)
yes they are...but I'm managing with some other way....but this solution was great...Thanks again..